# MySQL dynamic pivot table

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have simplified my data to something much like the following:

```
+---------+-----+--------+
| item  | type  | color  |
+-------+-------+--------+
|   1   |   A   | red    |
|   1   |   B   | blue   |
|   2   |   A   | orange |
|   2   |   B   | pink   |
|   2   |   C   | blue   |
|   3   |   B   | yellow |
+---------+-----+--------+
```

The number of 'type' per item is variable, therefore, I need a MySQL pivot solution that is dynamic and can handle any number of types.  The following is the kind of result set I need to return from the MySQL query.  As you can see, I do not need a summary calculation.

```
+---------+------+--------+--------+
| item  |   A    |   B    |   C    |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|   1   | red    | blue   |        | 
|   2   | orange | pink   | blue   |
|   3   |        | yellow |        |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I suspect the solution may involve the use of a MySQL procedure?

Comment: See this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ef81/2 and accept the duplicate :)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select item, min(A), min(B), min(C) from (
    select item, 
        case when type = 'A' then color end as 'A',
        case when type = 'B' then color end as 'B',
        case when type = 'C' then color end as 'C'
    from color
) as tbl
group by item
```

Comment: this works if the number of possible types is fixed, however the number of types may be fewer or greater.  So I need the mysql statement to dynamically adapt to the data.  This is why I suspect I may need a mysql procedure to build the case statements?

Answer (score 0):

You are "pivoting".  In [*my blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot), I provide a generic stored procedure to generate the `SELECT` statement for you.